# What is suspicious activity recorded in AbpAuditlogs ? what are their intentions?

Tags: security, aspnetboilerplate

I'have just receiving suspicious activity recorded in `AbpAuditlogs`.
`AbpAuditLogs.ClientIpAddress` contain this values:

```
;nslookup kHzJEuKV|nslookup kHzJEuKV&nslookup kHzJEuKV;
;nslookup V1UFHHC2|nslookup V1UFHHC2&nslookup V1UFHHC2;
-1 OR 2+329-329-1=0+0+0+1 --
(select(0)from(select(sleep(50.205)))v)/*'+(select(0)from(sel...
'+response.write(9330258*9027509)+'
;nslookup PICtOsP5|nslookup PICtOsP5&nslookup PICtOsP5;
)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))...
;nslookup PrqBZfl3|nslookup PrqBZfl3&nslookup PrqBZfl3;
```

anybody can help? Is my application under attack?
abp version 2.3.0 , mvc singalePageApplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a deep breath first. Look at the sky. Imagine you are floating on a big lump of rock in a vast universe. Good, now back to the logs.

Do they make sense? What is e.g. this: `-1 OR 2+329-329-1=0+0+0+1 --`? This is a SQL payload meant for searching for SQL injection vulnerabilities. It does no harm, it is meant only for reconnaissance. The next one? SQL too. This time blind SQL injection with a sleep inside. Will do no harm too. the next one? Code injection? Next one. Command line call. Next one - ok, the parentheses make little sense to me...

Someone is scanning you. Does it mean someone is attacking you? IMHO not yet. The stuff they are doing is meant for reconnaissance. There is no attack happening yet.

BTW. People do sometimes stupid things when they see stuff like this. Good thing you stayed calm.

Comment: you make my day "Take a deep breath first. Look at the sky" :D

Comment: Honestly, sometimes people shutdown their server when they see stuff like this. (They perform a DOS on their own infrastructure). Staying calm and thinking helps a lot.